# How to pass rows of a streaming pyspark dataframe to a ML model for inference

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a PySpark Streaming dataframe from Kafka having 2 columns: CamID, Frame. Frame column is having a list of byte encoded images as entries. I want to apply a Deep Learning based detection model to do inference in the frames. How to pass the 'Frame' column to that function? Will I be needing to iterate over the rows of 'Frame' column and push them to the detector function one-by-one? How to do this? This is my writeStream code snippet. I'm new to Kafka and PySpark, Please help.

```
frames_df4 = frames_df3.groupBy("CameraID").agg(collect_list("Frame"))

frames_write_stream = frames_df4 \
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime='1 seconds') \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .option("truncate", "false")\
    .format("console") \
    .start()

frames_write_stream.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at applyInPandas function https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html
Inside the function you can invoke the model and do inference.